# Ubuntu Touch: How do I run an ubuntu touch app from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

How do I run an ubuntu touch app from the terminal?
Where are they stored?

Comment: On what version of Ubuntu (Touch or Desktop, 14.04, 14.10, etc...), and on what hardware or configuration?

Comment: Nexus 7, Ubuntu Touch(Utopic)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> A convenient way for developers to do app testing is by starting them
>   through `adb`. To make that convenient we are providing a cli tool,
>   called `ubuntu-app-launch`.

So create a remote connection with `phablet-shell` and start your applications using their desktop filename:

```
ubuntu-app-launch com.ubuntu.calculator_calculator_1.3.316
ubuntu-app-launch dialer-app
```

You'll find your application desktop files in the following folders:

- `/usr/share/applications` for system apps and
- `~/.local/share/applications` for user apps.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Testing#Start_Applications_through_adb